# Trying to cast Listbox to a redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, listbox, response.redirect

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Session["lbSelectedMovies"] = lbDisplay;
        Session["lbSelectedSnacks"] = lbSelected;
        Response.Redirect("RingU6POSReview.aspx");
    (ListBox) lbTempMovies = (ListBox)Session["lbSelectedMovies"];
}
```

I am basically trying to create a page that redirects the user back to the main page... Response.Redirect("RingU6POS.aspx") under 2 conditions.

1. If the session carrying the movies is null
2. If the item count on the temporary type casted listbox is empty.

I believe I have the first issue solved with the following code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["lbSelectedMovies"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("RingU6POS.aspx");
    }
```

Does anyone know how to correctly code the casted element?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like (lbTempMovies as ListBox).Items.Any()?

Answer (score 1):

You can check all at once:

```
var lbTempMovies = (ListBox)Session["lbSelectedMovies"];
if (lbTempMovies == null || lbTempMovies.Items.Count == 0)
{
    Response.Redirect("RingU6POS.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code it will work

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Session["lbSelectedMovies"] = lbDisplay;
    Session["lbSelectedSnacks"] = lbSelected;

    if(Session["lbSelectedMovies"]!=null)
    {
       (ListBox) lbTempMovies = (ListBox)Session["lbSelectedMovies"];

       if(lbTempMovies==null || lbTempMovies.Items.Count==0)
       {
          Response.Redirect("RingU6POSReview.aspx");
       }
    }
    else
    {
      Response.Redirect("RingU6POSReview.aspx");
    }
}
```